# How does the toggle button work with checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox, twitter-bootstrap-3, togglebutton

I'm referring to the [Toggle buttons with checkboxes](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio) which I don't understand. There we have the example (I have added some ids):

```html
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input id="c1" type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" checked> Checkbox 1 (pre-checked)
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input id="c2" type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checkbox 2
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input id="c3" type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checkbox 3
  </label>
</div>
```

I can click on the third button or use `$('#c3').closest('.btn').button('toggle')` to set the third button as pressed. That is visually okay. However, the checkbox input does not get the `checked` attribute, and that is what I'm missing. Why doesn't this happen automatically? Am I required to do this manually?

### Update and solution:

As Marcos Pérez Gude revealed: The inspector of Firefox (or Elements in Chrome) doesn't show changes regarding the checked state of a checkbox. There you can modify or see other things but currently (Firefox 40) the checked state cannot be trusted. That was my fault.

Comment: Are you including bootstrap js file? And jquery library? Your console throws an error? Be more specific

Comment: Its actually `toggling` and you can find it with `$('#c1').closest('.btn').button('toggle')
console.log($("#c1").is(":checked"))`.. Visit the link given by you, open the `console`, and inspect the first `checkbox` there. Add an `id="c1"` by editing it as `html` and paste the above lines and run it.. You can actually see the state of `checkbox` changing

Comment: Or just right click the label and get inside the `checkbox` and from right side of `console` uncheck its property `position:absolute`. You can actually see check box on top and now try to toggle by click or by above code!

Comment: @GuruprasadRao On the bootstrap page when I click a button only the active class gets added or removed. The checked attribute of the input doesn't be changed. Tried this with Chrome and Firefox and watched the html.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude See my last comment, I have that problem already with the original example. It is not the problem with my code. It seems I don't get the concept.

Comment: checked doesn't change when you visualize in html and even though the property remains same the functional part [state of checkbox] gets updated.. weird but its happening..

Comment: Yes weird, that's why I'm wondering how to use it correctly.

Comment: No, in the inspector you can't view the change, but the checkbox is changed anyway. How matter if it appears in inspector or not? You can view the change in the DOM tree, not in the auto-browser-generated html

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Yes, you are right! The inspector doesn't show it. There the checked attribute won't get added or removed. But using `$('#c3').prop('checked')` returns true or false according to the visual state. Thanks, man!